# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version 3.5.0.0

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I have application use SDF file and I use System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version 3.5.0.0 I make it copy Local = true ; after make l'app in other PC without sql compact installation I got this error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version 3.5.0.0

I tried Embed Interop Types but it not work with ce dll.

the file existe in application directry; and I know that it read from Programme file but I have to install sql compact in any Pc I have to use application into ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to check out the following answer: [Sql Server CE 4 and EF 4.1 CF Win 64 bit deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049109/sql-server-ce-4-and-ef-4-1-cf-win-64-bit-deployment). It really helped me. It directs to another resource: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html.

Using this approach you don't need to install the SQL Server CE runtime. All the runtime travels with your app as a part of it.

Comment: I test it but same error ! I have to let the reference or delete it after include dll ?

Answer (score 1):

The dll needs to be registered as it wont work by just copying the dll in bin folder. You need to do the installation on 2nd pc as well or try including x64 and x86 binaries with your app.

Answer (score 1):

rename the user.config file located at 
C:\Users[USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\LandingPage.exe_StrongName_ryspccglaxmt4nhllj5z3thycltsvyyx\10.0.0.0 
TO (USER.CONFIG.BAK)