# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe'

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce

I have a .Net Framework 3 Winforms application that works with a SQLServerCE database.  I've just released my latest version, but on 2 of the users computers I got this message:

---

### Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

I have the following list of files in my application folder:

sqlceca35.dll

sqlcecompact35.dll

sqlceer35EN.dll

sqlceme35.dll

sqlceoledb35.dll

sqlceqp35.dll

sqlcese35.dll

System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.dll

Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.Server.dll

Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by setting the `Specific Version` property of the `System.Data.SqlServerCe` to **False**.

You can do this by right clicking on the Reference and clicking on Properties. After the properties window has opened, find the `Specific Version` property and set it to **False**.

Answer (score 1):

Solution : its worked to my system, issue closed
Install Microsoft SQL CE 3.5 that can be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5783

Install Microsoft SQL CE 4.0 SP1 that can be downloaded from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30709

Comment: Hello Raj, and welcome to Stack Overflow. From @amanda's question, it sounds like she is distributing software to user computers so wants Microsoft SQL CE to be embedded as part of that distribution. As per your answer, are you suggesting that Microsoft SQL CE needs to be installed on each client computer? Is there a way around that by including some of its DLLs in a project, or changing how its dependencies are registered within the project?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you check to make sure that these users have the version (and any updates, e.g. SP1, etc) of .NET 3.5 installed.

If the above doesn't work, try turning on Assembly Binding Viewer ([fuslogvw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) to see what is causing the assembly load failure, it's quite possible there is a dependency missing from SqlServerCe.dll

Comment: I was looking in the wrong place all the time thinking the problem is with the .NET framework.  Turns out that the installation of SQL Server CE wasn't run by my installer.  Run the 2 .msi installers and all working now.  Thanks.  Got the tip from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049109/sql-server-ce-4-and-ef-4-1-cf-win-64-bit-deployment